# Unable to read newline character from file

Tags: java

i have a file that contains the following content:

```
This is the content to write into file
POST /api/v1/jobs HTTP/1.1
Cache-Control: no-cache
---------------------------A495ukjfasdfddrg4hztzu898aA0jklm
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="sample.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
X-compId: data
Content-Length: 10
1234567891
---------------------------A495ukjfasdfddrg4hztzu898aA0jklm
```

When i try to read the newline in this file its not recognising the newline.
I know we have BufferedReader that reads the contents line by line but i have a requirement to identify the new lines in this file. Below is the code that I used to find the index of newline.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[READ_BUFFER_SIZE];

        int bytesRead=0;
        InputStream _baseStream =  new FileInputStream("slot.txt");
        BufferedInputStream buff =new BufferedInputStream(_baseStream);
        buff.mark(10);
        try {

            bytesRead = buff.read(buffer, 0, READ_BUFFER_SIZE);
            System.out.println("1. "+bytesRead);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        String stringBuffer = new String(buffer,java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset());
        int indexOfCrLf = stringBuffer.indexOf("\r\n");
        int indexOfPageStart = stringBuffer.indexOf("\r\n\r\n");
```

I also tried using

```
String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

For the newline char.still i get the index as -1.

Comment: Why don't you use a [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) ?

Comment: Why dont you use BufferedReader?

Comment: You're only reading a single "chunk" - there's no guarantee that that will fill the buffer. Beyond that, are you *certain* that the file contains "carriage return, line feed" rather than just a line feed?

Comment: Are you sure the file uses `\r\n` as newline and not `\n`?

Comment: In addition to Robert's comment: `System.getProperty("line.separator")` must not correspond to the actual line separator of the contents of your file.

Comment: Try to use regular expression `\r|\n\r|\n`, because different systems use different EOL delimiters.

Comment: Your code is working perfectly fine for me. I just tried to count the occurrences of new line by `StringUtils.countMatches(stringBuffer.toString(), "\n")` and it prints 9.